# How to get string after second slash in url - using jquery?

Tags: jquery, regex

How to get string after second slash in url?

I have this link :

```
https://en.exemple.com/invite/JiTY6s0ejuDAG3LNJq3YPEmL
```

I want to get this :

```
JiTY6s0ejuDAG3LNJq3YPEmL
```

I mean, after :

```
https://en.exemple.com/invite/
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this, for example this (if you're sure your URL always is of that form):

```js
const url = 'https://en.exemple.com/invite/JiTY6s0ejuDAG3LNJq3YPEmL';
const identifier = url.match(/invite\/(.*)$/)[1];

console.log(identifier);
```

No need for jQuery for this.

PS: next time please show what you attempted.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let url = "https://en.exemple.com/invite/JiTY6s0ejuDAG3LNJq3YPEmL";
let str = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions, you may read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp). The following solution works for any URL:

```
function getLastURLPart(url) {
    var part = url.match(/.*\/(.+)/);
    if(!part) {
        return null;
    }
    return part[1];
}
```

then you can just use it like this:

```
var url = "https://en.exemple.com/invite/JiTY6s0ejuDAG3LNJq3YPEmL";
console.log(getLastURLPart(url));
```

Also you can directly use the regExp like this:

```js
var url = "https://en.exemple.com/invite/JiTY6s0ejuDAG3LNJq3YPEmL";
alert(url.match(/.*\/(.+)/)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, which gives you access to all the parts of the url:

```js
const url = 'https://en.exemple.com/invite/JiTY6s0ejuDAG3LNJq3YPEmL';

const urlParts = url.split('/').filter(Boolean); // <-- split by '/' and remove empty parts

console.log(urlParts);
console.log(urlParts[3]); // <-- what you want
```